# How to call a process from an .exe file

Tags: batch-file, exe, executable, pyinstaller

I have a program called `test.exe`. The program was written in python/pyqt4. At some point along the code I want to trigger a restart of the application so I need to create a detached process which runs independent from the main process in order to fire the program and close the currently running one immediately after.

The problem is that it doesnt want to work no matter how I try. Instead of executing the same exe I also tried creating a .bat file which then calls the exe after a timeout (I added a ping to localhost).

If I try to execute some other program like a copy of notepad.exe it works with no issues but I can't get to a solution in order to restart an application. Here's my test code:

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

if getattr( sys, 'frozen', False ):
    ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( sys.executable ) )
elif __file__:
    ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath( __file__ ) )


class Example( QtGui.QWidget ):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI( self ):
        qbtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect( self.btn_clicked )
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

    def btn_clicked( self ):
        p = QtCore.QProcess()
        p.setWorkingDirectory( ROOT_PATH )
        p.startDetached( "start.bat" )
        sys.exit( 0 )

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `exe` is compiled using pyinstaller and in my final location I have `text.exe` and `start.bat` which looks like this:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 > "bat.txt"
start "" "%~dp0test.exe"
```

If I replace `test.exe` with `notepad.exe` in my bat file it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't be `%~dp0\test.exe"` (missing slash) ?

Comment: bat works fine if i click it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing another small exe which is watching for a file to appear (reset.txt). Main exe when restarting is `touching` the file then exits. The second exe runs as a daemon and when it sees the file calls the first exe.

Open for improvements...